# How to define colors in style file (lstlang0.sty)

Tags: listings, color

Per the `listings` package documentation, I have a file `lstlang0.sty` in the same directory as my .tex file (well, .lyx file) which defines a new language. I used to have this language definition in my preamble but since it's being used in at least four documents now, I am very motivated to maintain it as a separate style file.

I've defined colors to provide syntax highlighting and that's where things get hung up.

This block was previously in my preamble and now resides in my `lstlang0.sty` file. Note it used `lstdefinelanguage` in the preamble (no '@'). Also, I've snipped out most of the keywords for convenience.

```
\lst@definelanguage[CR]{Basic}{%
  basicstyle={\ttfamily\footnotesize},%
  sensitive=false,%
  upquote=true,%
  string=[bd][\color{crbString}]{"},%
  showstringspaces=false,%
  morekeywords=[1]{Const, Public, <snip> ...},%
  keywordstyle={[1]{\color{crbKeyword}}},%
  otherkeywords={=, /, *, +, -, *=, /=, +=, -=, <<, >>, ^, <, >},%
  morekeywords=[2]{=, /, *, +, -, *=, /=, +=, -=, <<, >>, ^, <, >},%
  keywordstyle={[2]{\color{crbKeyword}}},%
  morecomment={[l][\color{crbComment}\ttfamily\itshape]{'}}%
}
\endinput
```

Things compile correctly so long as the colors (`crbKeyword`, `crbString`, `crbComment`) are defined *in the preamble*. Attempting to define them in the style file like so:

```
\definecolor{crbString}{RGB}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{crbKeyword}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{crbComment}{RGB}{0,128,128}
\lst@definelanguage[CR]{Basic}{%
  ...
```

gives me a long list of errors:

```
LaTeX Error: Undefined color 'crbKeyword'.
LaTeX Error: Undefined color 'crbKeyword'.
LaTeX Error: Undefined color 'crbComment'.
...
```

I tried adding `\RequirePackage{color}` above the color definitions in the style file and LaTeX first complains "Can only be used in preamble" followed by the same undefined color errors. Encasing the color definitions with `\AtBeginDocument{..}` produced the same results.

What do I need to change to get the color definitions into `lstlang0.sty`?

---

I did notice no other `listings` language definitions include syntax coloring. Is there any (technical) reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The language definition files, despite using the file extension `.sty` aren't regular packages, so you can't put anything inside them other than `\lst@definelanguage` commands.  Instead, for other listings related LaTeX code, like your colour definitions, you should use the `listings.cfg` file.

So put the colour definitions there, and everything will work as you expect.

If you only want these definitions to work for a particular language, (in your case Basic), you can put them into a file named `listings-<language>.prf` and then in your `lstlocal.cfg` file you add `\input{listings-<language>.prf}`.  Both files can be placed in a `listings` directory within your local `texmf` directory.

So to be more explicit for your particular example, you can create the following files:

*listings-basic.prf*

```
\definecolor{crbString}{RGB}{255,0,255}
\definecolor{crbKeyword}{RGB}{0,0,255}
\definecolor{crbComment}{RGB}{0,128,128}
\endinput
```

*lstlocal.cfg*

```
\input{listings-basic.prf}
```

Or simply put the definitions directly into `lstlocal.cfg` and they will be available for any language definitions that use them.

Comment: I'm purposefully avoiding editing the MikTex distro files so I used the file name `lstlocal.cfg` instead of `listings.cfg` and placed the file in my working directory. Worked like a charm, thanks Alan Munn.

Comment: @pokeeffe That's actually a better route; I'll update the answer to show that.

Comment: @AlanMunn I'm not familiar with your recommended approach. Does it have benefits over writing a custom package with both language and colour definitions?

Comment: @Jubobs The advantage mainly lies in the fact that you are using a uniform interface via `listings` to access the language, so a separate package is simply not needed.  Since the `listings` package has set up this mechanism, it makes sense to use it (and it's a bit less work).